# git push "--force" required on windows but not on ubuntu, newly created repository

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, github

I created a new repository on github.com. I installed git version 1.8.4 on windows 7. I am usinf git bash for git related operations. I initialized git in an empty folder by

```
git init
```

command. Then I added remote for origin by command

```
git remote add origin <repo url>
```

Then I fetched the repository by command

```
git fetch origin
```

I added some files and then indexed them by git add command. Then I committed the files using

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

command. Then I tried to push using 
    git push 
command and I got following error.

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': Gaurav3khede
Password for 'https://Gaurav3khede@github.com':
To https://github.com/Gaurav3khede/TestRepo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Gaurav3khede/TestRepo.git
'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When my friend tried same thing on Ubuntu it worked fine.

```
tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ ls

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tarun/java_workspace/git_prac_g/.git/

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git remote add origin https://github.com/c2tarun/gaurav_test.git

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git fetch origin

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git branch

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ ls

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ echo "first file" >> Firstfile.txt

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ ls
Firstfile.txt

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# Firstfile.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git add .
tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) d6dec54] first commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 Firstfile.txt


tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': abc@abcmail.com
Password for 'https://abc@abcmail.com@github.com': 
To https://github.com/c2tarun/gaurav_test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

tarun:~/java_workspace/git_prac_g$
```

Now when I tried push command with --force option on windows then it worked. My question is in this scenario why do I need force option?

Comment: There is no `git push` on your Ubuntu example?

Answer (score 0):

**Why you usually do not need to force**

Say you have the following commits on the server

```
A -- B -- C
          L master
```

if you clone this repo and add a few commits, you would end up, in your local repo, with

```
A -- B -- C -- D ---- E ---- F
          L origin/master    L master
```

Here, you have no problem to push, and after `git push origin master`, the repo on the server will look like

```
    A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
                             L master
```

**Why you may need to force**

On the other hand, imagine someone else pushed some commits before you. Then you could have:

On the server:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- G -- H
                         L master
```

and if you fetch, you will have in your local repo:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- G -- H
                \        L origin/master
                 \
                  \- E -- F
                          L master
```

Here you will likely want to merge `H` and `F` and then push. But most of the time you don't want to just push `F`, because it would overwrite `H`.

So git tells you "beware, something wrong is going on and might result in a loss of data. But if you know what you're doing, go ahead and force".

If you `git push -f origin master`, Git will believe you know what you do, and the server will end up like

```
    A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
                             L master
```

That is: commits `G` and `H` are more or less lost.

**Conclusion**

It doesn't matter whether you're on windows or on ubuntu: you might need to force according to your local and remote repos. Not your OS.

The "technical" word would be: you can push only if it results in a `fast-forward` in the remote repo. You might want to search for this word on http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-2.html to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for superb explanation. I looked into fast-forwarding. My understanding is that if I pull and then merge then my local is automatically eligible for fast-forwarding. But in my case my repository was new and blank. Still I had to use --force. Any ideas about that?

Comment: According to your question, your local repo was indeed new and blank. But are we sure the remote repo was empty too? Anyway, to understand what's going on you could do, after having fetch `gitk --all`, to see where each branches (local and remote) are.